# More $or statements in mongoid merge to one and produces wrong results

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

In orders table inc_id = 1, have status `canceled`, so when I run this in mongo shell, I don't get any results

```
db.orders.find({
  $or: [{status:'canceled'}, {status:'booked'}],
  $or: [{status:'booked'}, {status: 'completed'}],
  inc_id: 1
})
```

but when I run same using mongoid in ruby on rails

```
orders = Order.where({"$or": [{status:'canceled'}, {status:'booked'}]})
orders = orders.where({"$or": [{status:'booked'}, {status: 'completed'}]})
orders = orders.where(:inc_id => 1)
```

result is inc_id 1 record. The query is executed in this fashion

```
db.orders.find({
  $or: [{status:'canceled'}, {status:'booked'},
        {status: 'completed'}],
  inc_id: 1
})
```

How can I achieve former behaviour with mongoid

Software Details:

- Mongoid: gem 'mongoid', '~>6.0.3'
- Mongo: MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
- OS: Mac OSX

Comment: Can you explain in words which records you want your query to return?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Order.where("$and" => [{ "$or" => [{status: 'canceled'}, {status: 'booked'}] },
                       { "$or" => [{status: 'booked' }, {status: 'completed'}] }])
     .where(inc_id: 1)
```